# 2005 Toyota Avalon how to reactivate vehicle's ECU

Tags: toyota, electronic-control-module, fob, avalon

2005 Toyota Avalon FOB stopped working, have a replacement.  Now believe accidentally deactivated vehicle's ECU by turning ignition on/off 5 times during process of adding new FOB. So now, how can I get receiver in car to accept signal codes from remote? It is not a smart key system!

Comment: Vehicle starts with key. This is about door lock/unlock feature with remote. I tried that procedure multiple times with failure. At end, locks recycled twice rather than once indicating non-acceptance of remote code. In error I turned ignition on/off 5X repeatedly placing in deactivation mode. (Theft prevention feature if stolen/lost). And this is why i believe ECU needs to be reactivated because it is not receiving the signal code from FOB. Otherwise, a timing problem needing synchronizing. And now need to know how to make it work. I would appreciate any input on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to make sure I am answering the question. Why do you believe that the ECU has been deactivated? Does the car not start?

Not sure of the procedure that your used, but take a look at these instructions and try to reprogram the remote.

Remove the key from the ignition. Lock all of the doors, but open the driver’s side door. Leave it unlocked. Insert the key into the ignition twice within five seconds. Don’t turn it. Close then open the door twice. Insert the key again then remove it from the ignition.

Close then open the driver’s side door. Close then open the driver’s side door again. Insert the key. Leave it in the ignition. Close the door. Turn the key to “On,” without starting the engine, and then turn it off. Remove the key. You’ll hear the door locks sound.

Push and hold “Lock” and “Unlock” buttons on the remote for two seconds, and then release the buttons. Then push and hold “Lock” for three seconds. The remote is now programmed.

After this the remote should work after this. If the car would not start before, try it after locking the car with the remote, unlocking it and then open the drivers door put the key in and try to start it.

Again, not sure I'm answering this correctly based on your short description.  If not, try to clarify the issue and we'll see if there is a better answer.

Comment: Vehicle starts with key. This is about door lock/unlock feature with remote. I tried that procedure multiple times with failure. At end, locks recycled twice rather than once indicating non-acceptance of remote code. In error I turned ignition on/off 5X repeatedly  placing in deactivation mode. (Theft prevention feature if stolen/lost). And this is why i believe ECU needs to be reactivated because it is not receiving the signal code from FOB. Otherwise, a timing problem needing synchronizing. And now need to know how to make it work. I would appreciate any input on this problem.

Comment: After the door locks lock twice, telling you the remote was not accepted, try pushing the lock and unlock again for 2seconds, then the lock button for 3 seconds.  See if it cycles one time, indicating the remote is programmed.  What do you mean when you say the ECU is deactivated? You state the car starts. Do you mean the remotes are not accepted so you think the ECU is deactivated?

Comment: In response to your last question, that is exactly what I think now. After numerous attempts vehicle locks will not cycle at all and should cycle once indicating acceptance of remote code. Remote has code that sends signal and can not be programmed. The vehicle's receiver (ECU) should be on/awake/activated to receive a signal from FOB (remote). This is how i concluded receiver is now deactivated. Hoping don't need Toyota software program to fix. (Saw charts indicating settings from Techstream data.) Note: Previously, receiver was awake but not accepting remote after procedure. And now not!